# Firebird computed (calculated) field on server side

Tags: firebird, calculated-field, divide-by-zero, computed-field

Newbie in SQL and development in general, I have a table (COUNTRIES) with fields (INDEX, NAME, POPULATION, AREA)
Usually i add a client side (Delphi) Calculated field (DENSITY) and OnCalcField :

```
COUNTRIES.DENSITY=COUNTRIES.POPULATION / COUNTRIES.AREA
```

Trying to change to Firebird computed field to have all calculation done on server side, i created a field named density and in IBEXPERT "Computed Source" column :

```
ADD DENSITY COMPUTED BY ((((COUNTRIES.POPULATION/COUNTRIES.AREA))))
```

Everything work fine but when a Record.AREA = 0 i have a Divided by zero error.

My question is how to avoid this for example with a IF THEN condition to avoid to calculate a field when the divider is 0 or to make the result just =0 in this case.

My environnement :
Delphi RIO, Firebird 3.0, IBExpert

Comment: `ADD DENSITY COMPUTED BY (CASE WHEN COUNTRIES.AREA = 0 THEN 0 ELSE COUNTRIES.POPULATION / COUNTRIES.AREA END)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use IIF(). When the 1st parameter is TRUE, IIF returns value of the second parameter, otherwise of the third parameter.

```
ADD DENSITY COMPUTED BY (IIF(COUNTRIES.AREA = 0, 0, COUNTRIES.POPULATION / COUNTRIES.AREA))
```

(note I also removed some extra parenthesis)

When handling division by zero, I recommend returning NULL (instead of zero), with a simple use of NULLIF (internal function which returns null, when both input parameters are equal):

```
ADD DENSITY COMPUTED BY (COUNTRIES.POPULATION / nullif(COUNTRIES.AREA, 0))
```

That is: when COUNTRIES.AREA = 0, the whole division operation results in null, too.